# Amazon Route 53 setup subdomain to point to Load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, amazon-route53

I have 2 services running on AWS.
Lets say my domain is example.com

I run both of them through Elasticbeanstalk.

One is a single EC2 instance with a elastic IP setup and running on the apex - `example.com` and `www.example.com` which works correctly and i can access it.

The other one is a service that has a load balancer in front and i want it to be accessible through sockets.example.com which i cannot get to work.

I have the route 53 nameservers setup in namecheap.com from where i bought the domain.

Here is my whole setup:

[image: Current Route 53 setup]

**EDIT:**

I can get the URl from the `alias target` and open it in a browser for example or ping it. That works.

I have the loadbalancer setup to forward the traffic from 80 to 8080 where my sockets are because of the root access rights for attaching them with sockets i was unable to set them up on the lower ports such as 80. But i don't think thats the issue since i am running a node.js app and i can open a sample page if i go straight on the Alias target URL.

Comment: how long did you wait for the DNS to propagate? even in route53, I've had to wait up to 20 mins for a subdomain to become available

Comment: Its been 1 day now. its too long.

Comment: indeed, that's an issue. is the domain resolved? what happens when you try to ping it?

Comment: Possibly not a DNS issue, I suspect your Elastic Load Balancer is in HTTP mode, which doesn't support websockets.  It needs to be in TCP mode.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c47hv19rgydb6nu/Screenshot%202014-08-15%2015.07.56.png

Comment: edited my question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your ELB up as public or internal?